# CKEditor BootstrapCollapse won't load

Tags: bootstrap-4, ckeditor

This is the CKEditor config.js file, the bootstrapCollapse plugin won't load, do what you want but I cannot get it working.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbar = [
        { name: 'document', items: [ 'Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt' ] },
        { name: 'forms', items: [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 'HiddenField' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language' ] },
        { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },
        { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', items: [ 'Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },
        { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks' ] },
        { name: 'about', items: [ 'About' ] },
        { name: 'bootstrapCollapse', items: [ 'BootstrapCollapse' ] }
    ];

    config.extraPlugins = 'bootstrapCollapse';
    config.contentsCss = 'costumbootstrap/css/bootstrap.css';
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.bootstrapCollapse_managePopupContent = true;
    config.extraPlugins = 'widget';
    config.extraPlugins = 'lineutils';  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting one `config.extraPlugins` setting with another. All [`config.extraPlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins) should be listed in one declaration, as in:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'bootstrapCollapse,widget,lineutils';
```

Also make sure that all additional plugins are actually included in your CKEditor package.

Comment: overwriting fixed, plugin is nicely CKEditor package, browser cashe cleared. cdeditor is just empty, don't show show ckeditor. I don't know i know its not plugin support but worked hardly to get working that!

Comment: It would be much easier for the community to investigate this if you created a working sample on JSFiddle or CodePen. Check the browser console for any errors, too.